# Chrome pinch and zoom before DOM is loaded blocks the zoom value

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

This is a very specific problem.
If I pinch and zoom into Chrome **before** DOM is loaded, then Chrome thinks this zoom value is the default one. I have to close the tab, and reopen it in order to recover a correct value.

It keeps the page zoomed in though I set it to 100%.

I thinks it's a bug from chromium, do you know any workaround ?

To test it :

- Open a tab with developer window on mobile/tablet devices mode
- Load a page, and very quickly set the zoom to 150%
- Try to set zoom to 100%

I tried to set meta-viewport as follow without success:

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
```

Also, I'm using it in Kiosk mode, I do want pinch and zoom in my application.

Answer (score 0):

For those who encounter this bug.
My constrains were the following :

- Application in Kiosk mode
- Only touchscreen is available
- The thouchscreen has ghost clicks that makes Chrome zoom in before it's fully initialize.
- Solution [Disable Chrome pinch zoom for use in kiosk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22999829/disable-chrome-pinch-zoom-for-use-in-kiosk?rq=1) doesn't work, ghost clicks happen before --disable-pinch is active.

Workaround : Emulate CTRL+0 shortcut every x minutes/seconds to force zoom reset