# Chromium selenium webdriver disable zoom-in option

Tags: selenium, chromium

I am trying to find a way to disable zoom in option in selenium webdriver, I am using chromium and there is no command line switch for this in docs, browser is in kiosk mode with touchscreen and user are able to zoom-in with two fingers, how to prevent that?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23057591/16399561) help you?

Comment: Yes, thank you.