# Automatically display touch keyboard on HTML input in Chromium Kiosk mode

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, html-input, kiosk

I am running Chromium in kiosk mode:

```
chrome.exe --kiosk http://127.0.0.1:1234/
```

for an embedded (desktop) computer, which a touch monitor only (no keyboard, no mouse).

**Is there a way to configure desktop Chromium to behave like a mobile/touch UI?

More precisely, how to make that when clicking/touching a HTML `<input>` element, an on-screen keyboard similar to the one displayed on Chrome for Android is automatically displayed?**

Note: I'd like to do this directly at Chrome level, and, if possible, avoid to use a third-party extension like [Virtual Keyboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/virtual-keyboard/pflmllfnnabikmfkkaddkoolinlfninn) or a [JS library like this one](https://virtual-keyboard.js.org/).

[image]

Comment: (I mis-typed the bounty text, the goal is just: find a useful working answer)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone reading in 2022 - those flags does not open on screen keyboard (tested on touchscreen monitor)

Answer (score 0):

Adding these extra chrome flags used to work previously, however I cannot confirm as I do not have a touchscreen monitor at the moment:

```
chrome.exe --kiosk --touch-events -enable-viewport http://127.0.0.1:1234/
```

Also you may want to consider the following, it may also apply to Chromium: [Disable Chrome pinch zoom for use in kiosk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22999829/)

Comment: Thanks @djmonki, does it display an on-screen virtual keyboard? Or only enable the touchscreen events?

Comment: A while ago, when chrome was in version 80+,, it did launch the default os on-screen keyboard, but it was an experimental flag back then. It was something that we did for my kid as a POC, but the screen died, so not done it since. No promises.