# Is there a way to remove zooming from cefsharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Hello im building an c# winforms app for my windows tab. I can zoom in and zoom out with 2 fingers. So i want to remove zoom event. How can i remove the zoom event ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj2z7.png)

Comment: Guys please help this is so important for me

Answer (score 0):

I googled "cefsharp disable zoom", and the three first results say you can do

```
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-pinch", "1");
```

to disable pinch zooming.

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23057591/51685